# Is that possible to create db migration for dynamo db in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb

I am using rails 3 and for dynamo db using 'aws-sdk' gem . And I have some doubt in db migration.

1) Is that possible to create db migration for dynamo db in ruby on rails?

2) If so how to write? Because of the dynamo db has no table field name only key value pairs, we need to create only table and primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write migrations for DynamoDB in Rails; the AWS-SDK gem does not provide support for it. You have to create the tables manually or use a gem.

And if you're looking for a gem that supports this stuff... unfortunately by and large it doesn't exist yet. If you'll excuse the shameless self-promotion though, I'm actually writing a DynamoDB Rails adapter right now; you can check it out [at the Dynamoid github repository](https://github.com/Veraticus/Dynamoid). I don't think I'd call it production ready yet, but it could give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot write migrations for DynamoDB tables, I created a [small rake task](https://gist.github.com/3974694) to do migration-like activities.  It has two tasks, create & delete, which create all the tables or delete all the tables respectively.

Its not very fancy and could use some parameters & error checking but it seems to work.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Also a selfish plug - because there isn't much out there for DynamoDb yet...

You can check out [Mince Dynamo Db](https://github.com/coffeencoke/mince_dynamo_db).  When using with [Mince](https://github.com/coffeencoke/mince) in a rails or standard ruby app you can develop your application using a ruby hash as your database and switch it to Amazon's DynamoDb database in staging and production.

If you need behavior that does not exist yet, like creating tables, and changing throughput capacity levels, put in an issue into github.  This library is being used in production right now.